# can someone create a git repository with past date

Tags: git, github, repository, git-push

I'm still new to github, I created a lot of projects in the past but I didn't push them .
So I wonder, can someone create a repo in the past and push his code with past dates ?
I tried to change my pc time & date but it didn't work .

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change commit's date. But it is possible to [amend](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history) commit and alter it's date.

Saying that there are two dates, commit date and author date. To change commit date set `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`. Then use `git commit --amend --no-edit`.

To change author date, use `git commit --amend --no-edit --date="new date"`

Comment: This does not *change* the commit's date. It makes a *new and different commit* that is exactly the same as the original commit except for the date stamp. A distinction without a difference? Yes and no: if you find commits by branch names and don't notice that the hash IDs have changed, you'll never know that this happened: it *seems like* the date of the commit *changed*. If you're Git itself, though, and pay attention to hash IDs, you'll notice that you now have the old commit *and* the new commit, and are using the new commit via the branch name.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, I updated an answer

Answer (score 0):

The date a commit was made will show up on the commit. Just create a new repo, push your existing content into it and the commits will have the date as they are in your local repo. The data s stored as part of the commit metadata.